# Create a dict whose values update every time its is used

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary that updates its keys every time it is used

What I have tried:

```py
import itertools

changing_dict = {
    "key1": next(change),
    "key2": next(change),
    "key3": next(change),
    "key4": 10010
}

print(changing_dict)
# Output
# {'key1': 100, 'key2': 105, 'key3': 110, 'key4': 10010}

print(changing_dict)
# Output
# {'key1': 100, 'key2': 105, 'key3': 110, 'key4': 10010}
```

Expected Output

```py
print(changing_dict)
# Output
# {'key1': 100, 'key2': 105, 'key3': 110, 'key4': 10010}

print(changing_dict)
# Output
# {'key1': 115, 'key2': 120, 'key3': 125, 'key4': 10010}
```

Any help on how I can do this or is this even possible as iterable values are calculated while dict creation.

> The actual problem is creating configuration files where every time this dict is used, I get it with new port numbers.

Comment: You want to have a function that returns a different dict everytime it is called.

Comment: Not with a standard dict, but it might possible with a custom dict-like class.  I sense an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) though — what is it that you're _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: And what happens if the generator comes to an end, i.e. `StopIteration`?

Comment: 1. When you say the "dict is **called**", what exactly do you mean by that? (We don't really "call" a dictionary.)  2. Why does this have to be a magic dict and can't be a specialized class or function?

Comment: It can be. I got my answer below and will accept it, not sure how I missed this simple thing though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this function, you can have a function, so every-time it runs, the `change` variable will be different:

```
change = iter(range(100, 200, 5)) # just an example

def next_dict():
    changing_dict = {
        "key1": next(change),
        "key2": next(change),
        "key3": next(change),
        "key4": 10010
    }
    return changing_dict
print(next_dict())
print(next_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'key1': 100, 'key2': 105, 'key3': 110, 'key4': 10010}
{'key1': 115, 'key2': 120, 'key3': 125, 'key4': 10010}
```

Comment: Sure, also may I suggest an edit, change your                                                      
change = iter(range(100, 200, 5)) # just an example to change = itertools.count(100, 5) # just an example

Comment: @piyushdaga Sure, i would approve it, total of 4 points from this post you would get

Comment: @piyushdaga where is it?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a class instead of a dictionary like that:

```
change = iter(range(5))

class c:
    def get_key1():
        return next(change)

c.get_key1() # Output: 0
c.get_key1() # Output: 1
```

Like some of the comments, I suggest you give more context, as there might be a more 'Pythonic' was to address you use case.